# epstopdf - EPS files with same name

Tags: pdftex, pdf, eps, epstopdf

My project has EPS files of the same name saved in a nested folder structure. For example, I have files **~/folder/sub1/foo.eps** and **~/folder/sub2/foo.eps**. In my tex file, I have the following epstopdf setup:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{
suffix=,
outdir=./include/eps_to_pdf/
}
```

I then include the two figures as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{../../folder/sub1/foo}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{../../folder/sub2/foo}
\end{figure}
```

However, the figures both compile as the first figure. As I understand, this is because the first EPS with this name is converted to PDF and, because there now exists a PDF with that name, epstopdf will skip over the conversion process for any future EPS with that name.

Thus, my question is: what are the recommended workarounds for this? Ideally, there would be an approach that doesn't require converting the EPS to PDF every time I compile. However, this is preferred to renaming my files because this is not an isolated example.

Comment: why should you convert everytime? Convert them once when putting them in the folder and put them beside the eps.

Comment: Right now, I haven't even figured out a way to convert them every time, and I agree it doesn't make much sense. Is there a setting for epstopdf that would tell it to output the PDFs in the same place as the EPS files? I thought that it only takes one static folder.. and thus I don't know how I'd tell it to output to both "folder/sub1" and "folder/sub2" if that makes sense.

Comment: simply call `epstopdf foo` on a terminal in the folder.

Comment: OTP: it's bad form to name files identical. use distinct file names for each instead.